# Maven [WARNING] Parameter 'localRepository' is deprecated core expression... and what?

Tags: maven

The latest version of `maven-assembly-plugin` gives the following warning:

```
[INFO] --- assembly:3.5.0:single (default) @ my-project ---
[WARNING] Parameter 'localRepository' is deprecated core expression; Avoid use of ArtifactRepository type. If you need access to local repository, switch to '${repositorySystemSession}' expression and get LRM from it instead.
```

I have the `<localRepository>` parameter in my `settings.xml`.

What can I do to avoid this warning?

Comment: You can't... It will be solved with the next release of the maven-assembly-plugin (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-974)

Comment: I see the same issue, but I can't find where it's being thrown from.

Answer (score 0):

you should replace the variable  to <repositorySystemSession.localRepository>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).